# Wrapping img src in " " when rendering react state

Tags: reactjs

I have a small application, which uses to giphy API to fetch a GIF and display it as an image.

```
<img src={this.state.gifUrl} alt="mood"></img>
        <p> here it is: {this.state.gifUrl}</p>
```

the image URL prints out fine, but it shows a blank image. how can i wrap my react expression using " " making it valid HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should need is the following, JSX will automatically wrap it for you. If it's not displaying correctly I'd double check to the URL to make sure it resolves to an actual image and not leaf page.

```
<img src={this.state.gifUrl} />
```

Comment: I figured the issue, was because it could not display a gif url inside an <img> tag

Answer (score 1):

here is an example that work. Passing a variable to render the src attribute

const Img = () => {
const data = 'https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Savannah-cat-long-body-shot.jpg'
return (
      
    )
}